# Has anyone heard of this "3-Edge-Coloring Conjecture"?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

I found this one on openproblemgarden.org but can't seem to find any references of it outside of there. The problem is listed as of "high importance". Have you heard of this conjecture? (link [here](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/3_edge_coloring_conjecture))

**Conjecture**   Suppose $G$ with $|V(G)|>2$ is a connected cubic graph admitting a $3$-edge coloring. Then there exists an edge $e \in E(G)$ such that the cubic graph homeomorphic to $G-e$ has a $3$-edge coloring.

(as a side note, do they mean **any** graph homeomorphic to $G-e$? Using the wording "the" doesn't make much sense to me)

Comment: Regarding your side note - I think there is only one *cubic* graph homeomorphic to $G-e$, namely the graph you get by by smoothing out the two end vertices of the removed edge $e$.